# How do I avoid java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException when using Gatling Frontline with compiled code?

Tags: java, scala, sbt, protocol-buffers, gatling

I'm using Gatling Frontline to run load tests written in scala with sbt as the build tool. The project compiles, builds, and runs successfully locally. However, when running on a Frontline host, the host fails to connect to the injector pool because the injector process has crashed with an Exception in thread "main" `java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException`. The stack trace indicates that this exception is caused by

```
java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/google/protobuf/ByteString$Output
```

and

```
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.google.protobuf.ByteString$Output.
```

This error has never occurred locally, during development, as this google package is not used by my project. Could this problem be fixed by changing any of the jvm options supplied by Frontline, or by adding certain system properties or build properties.

Comment: It would help me if you posted the entire stack trace formatted as it appears when you run your code.

Comment: Please reach out to support. I guess you use FrontLine's offer on the AWS MarketPlace: https://aws.amazon.com/marketplace/pp/Gatling-Corp-Gatling-FrontLine-High-Scale-Load-Tes/B07DTWPZG8. You'll find support email address in there (not sure if it can be posted here).

Comment: Showing your `build.sbt` will also help.